# finding and analyzing critical points

Tags: calculus

This is the function:
$$f(x,y)=xye ^{-x-y}$$
I have trouble finding critical points and fxx, fyy and fxy.
I think fx is 
$$fx=(x-1)y(-e ^{-x-y)}$$
$$fy=x(y-1)(-e ^{-x-y)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partials are
$${f_x} = y{e^{ - x - y}}(1 - x)$$
$${f_y} = x{e^{ - x - y}}(1 - y)$$
so your answers are correct. With these you can find ${f_{xx}}$, ${f_{yy}}$ and ${f_{xy}}$ using the product rule and the chain rule.

Comment: so i got fxx=e^(-x-y), fyy=e^(-x-y)+y-1 and fxy=e^(-x-y)+y-1

Comment: D(x,y)=(e^(-x-y)+y)(e^(-x-y)+y-1) -(e^(-x-y)+y-1)^2

Comment: I think ${f_{xx}} = y{e^{ - x - y}}(x - 2) = {f_{yy}}$.

Comment: are you sure about it?

Comment: Yes. Take $y{e^{ - x - y}}$ and $(1 - x)$, then use the product rule and the chain rule. Then take $x{e^{ - x - y}}$ and $(1 - y)$ to compute ${f_{yy}}$. Do not forget to factor.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the exponential function is always positive(or negative). So, for $f_x = 0$, you have either $x = 0$  or $y =0$ and in the $f_y = 0$, you have $x = 0$ or $y=1$. Now, what are the critical points???? You know should be able to find them.

Comment: (0,0), (1,1)? but i have a hard time finding fxx and fyy and fxy now.